# Update a view without refresh?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am designing two view in MVC. In one,i can insert data and another for retrieve . How to update retrieve view after inserting data with out refresh. I know this is possible using Ajax only but how to do.. give an example please.

Comment: you need to do some AJAX calls on a timer in such a case....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax.BeginForm(). Probably [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx) is what you are trying to do.